# How to enable Gzip compression for getting Prometheus metrics?

Tags: c#, prometheus, prometheus-net

I'm using Prometheus (Prometheus.KestrelMetricServer) to export our services metrics.

Everything is working but although the `Accept-Encoding` header is set to `gzip`, the response of `GET localhost:port/metrics` is still not compressed.

Does Prometheus support compression for export metrics?

And if so, how can I tell Prometheus to send metrics compressed? (either as gzip, defalte or ...)

**UPDATE:** It's a Console app (not a WebApi). So the `Prometheus.KestrelMetricServer` itself serves the `/metrics` (instead of IIS or Kestrel or ...). I am looking for a way to compress the response by `Prometheus.KestrelMetricServer` itself

Comment: Yes it does. [Documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/exposition_formats/#text-based-format). Since request came with header `Accept-Encoding:gzip` it would be strange if it didn't.

Comment: @markalex Yes, documentation says that. But neither ``Accept-Encoding`` nor ``Content-Encoding`` causes the response to be compressed(as I checked the transferred size)

Comment: `Content-Encoding` have to be set by the server (as well as compression). You need to look into your lib's documentation to activate compression (if standalone mode used)  or configure own web-server to return compressed response (if middleware mode).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging more into this, looks like the Prometheus.KestrelMetricServer doesnt support Gzip compression and thats as per the design. Here is the [ISSUE](https://github.com/prometheus-net/prometheus-net/issues/141) from their github repo from 2019:

> After considering this feature request, I have decided to reject it
> from the backlog.
>
> The reason is that there is already available the ASP.NET Core metric
> server, which is significantly more flexible in what it supports,
> allowing you to incorporate custom middleware (such as gzip) into the
> pipeline. Please use the ASP.NET Core server for such scenarios.
>
> The Kestrel server is kept at a minimal feature set in maintenance
> mode and is unlikely to receive significant updates in future
> versions.

As I see it, you have some work arounds:

**WEB applications:**

One possible workaround could be to use a reverse proxy, such as **Nginx**, to sit in front of your Kestrel server and handle the compression.

Use a different Prometheus exporter such as the **Prometheus.AspNetCore** package. It supports Gzip compression out of the box, so you would not need to make any additional configuration changes.

**Console Applications**

Manually handle the HTTP requests and responses by using the [HTTPListener](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistener?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-7.0)

Something like this:

```
var httpListener = new HttpListener();
httpListener.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:9199/");
httpListener.Start();

while (httpListener.IsListening)
{
    var myContext = httpListener.GetContext();
    var myRequest = context.Request;
    var myResponse = context.Response;

    if (myRequest.Url.LocalPath == "/metrics")
    {
        var acceptEncoding = myRequest.Headers["Accept-Encoding"];
        if (acceptEncoding != null && acceptEncoding.Contains("gzip"))
        {
            myResponse.Headers.Add("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
            myResponse.OutputStream = new System.IO.Compression.GZipStream(response.OutputStream, System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Compress);
                }
```

Comment: Thanks for your attention. But I'm not using WebAPI. Take a look at question's update

Comment: sure, can you please check the new response. Hope that helps.